# How to use placeholder in Spring config without any properties files?

Tags: spring, properties, placeholder, properties-file

I want to have just a single property and I don't want to create a separate properties file for that. I want to inject it in a bean using the `@Value` annotation like this:

```
@Value("#{my.placeholder}") private String lol;
```

as well use in other bean configuration like:

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="${my.placeholder}"/>
</bean>
```

How can I achieve that without using property files?

Comment: It can be anything system property, environment property, servlet context init parameter. Nonetheless you need the `<context:property-placeholder />` in your configuration else it won't work.

Answer (score -2):

You can use @Value("someValue") private String lol;

In this case you won't need any properties file.